# Nested writes in Prisma orm

Tags: prisma, prisma2

My schema looks like this:

```
model Transaction {
 id                 BigInt       @id @default(autoincrement())
 description        String?      @db.VarChar(256)
 category           Category?    @relation(fields: [categoryId], references: [id])
 createdById        Int          @map("fk_created_by")
 createdBy          UserAccount  @relation("category_fk_created_byTouser_account", fields: [createdById], references: [id]
}

model Category {
  id                      Int                     @id @default(autoincrement())
  name                    String                  @db.VarChar(40)
  categoryFilters         CategoryFilter[]
}

model CategoryFilter {
  id                  BigInt         @id @default(autoincrement())
  words               String         @db.VarChar(255)
  categoryId          Int?           @map("fk_category_id")
}
```

My question is why this works:

```
  await prisma.workspaceTransaction.create({
    data: {
      description: 'any',
      createdBy: {
        connect: {
          id: 1
        }
      },
      category: {
        create: {
          name: 'Este é um teste',
          createdById: 1,
          categoryFilters: {
            createMany: {
              data: [
                {
                  words: 'Novo teste'
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })
```

And this not?

```
await prisma.workspaceTransaction.create({
    data: {
      description: 'any',
      createdById: 1,
      category: {
        create: {
          name: 'Este é um teste',
          createdById: 1,
          categoryFilters: {
            createMany: {
              data: [
                {
                  words: 'Novo teste'
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })
```

The only difference between those two examples is in createdBy command. And i can create Transaction without nested objects with createdById argument. Any one know why this works this way? Or there is something i am missing?

The error given is:
Unknown arg `createdById` in data.createdById for type TransactionCreateInput

Answer (score 1):

In the second example, you are directly writing a foreign key (createdById) which is considered unsafe, what if there is no `UserAccount` corresponding to `createdById`.

While using `connect` in the first example it would throw an error if Prisma cannot find an `UserAccount` corresponding to `id` 1.

First example is the preferred approach.

Comment: I know that createdById is unsafe but i have one middleware (express) where I already select the user for auth propose. I did not want make another select (becouse connect make). My question is: why i cannot use createdById toguether with some create relation